# c# Проверка запуска TCP-сервера

Tags: c#, сервер, tcp

У меня есть мой api-сервер, который общается с БД. Это обычное консольное приложение, которое посылает запросы в БД и возвращает в приложение. Сервер должен запускаться вместе с основной программой. То есть, запускается программа, потом сам сервер (консольное приложение), потом подключаемся к серверу (создаём "клиента") и "слушаем" его.

Само подключение к серверу (создание "клиента") - классический tcp-сервер (System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.CreateChannel()).

Итак, суть самой проблемы - после запуска самой программы я запускаю сервер, но возникает проблема - из-за того, что он запускается не моментально - программе не удаётся подключиться к нему и вылезает ошибка (что и естественно - ведь сам сервак ещё не успел запуститься). Как можно "по-умному" реализовать проверку, окончательно ли запустился сервер, без Thread.Sleep и прочего ожидания

Код клиента:

```
var tcpUri = new Uri($"net.tcp://{serviceAddress}/{serviceName}");
        var address = new EndpointAddress(tcpUri);
        var clientBinding = new NetTcpBinding();
        clientBinding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None;
        ChannelFactory<ITransfer> factory = new(clientBinding, address);
        return factory.CreateChannel();
```

Код сервера:

```
var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Transfer), new Uri($"net.tcp://{serviceAddress}/{serviceName}"));
            var serverBinding = new NetTcpBinding();
            serverBinding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None;
            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ITransfer), serverBinding, "");
            host.Open();
```

Comment: Через try-catch в несколько попыток?

Comment: У меня именно так сейчас и стоит. Пытается запустить. Если не получилось - ждёт 15 секунд и повторяет попытку. Думал, есть ли какое-то более элегантное решение этой проблемы